# Can I track the absolute position of an NSView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nsnotificationcenter

Is it possible to be notified whenever the absolute (screen) position of an NSView changes?

I see there are notifications available for frame/bounds, but there are many cases where that won't change even though the position changed, e.g., when a view is in a clipview in a scrollview.  I can also track the position of the window itself.

Comment: Observe frame changes of the view and all of its superviews.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'm on a different project for the moment, but I will try that and see if it's as simple as it seems.